# CSS transition not animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

Can't figure this out, need another pair of eyes.  The footer is dispalyed properly at the bottom of the page.  On click, the trace appears in the console.  Not animating the transition in any browser.  THANKS for looking!!

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/appoverwrite.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/appscripts.js"></script>

<div id="appfooter">....</div>
```

APPOVERWRITE.CSS

```
#appfooter {
 position:fixed;
 width: 100%;
 bottom: -350px;
 height: 400px;
 clear:both;
 font-size: 11px;
 background: #000;
 border-top: 1px dotted #d83800;    
 z-index: 1000;
 transition: bottom 2s;
 -moz-transition: bottom 2s;
 -webkit-transition: bottom 2s;
 -o-transition: bottom 2s;
}

#appfooter .transition {
 bottom: 0px;
}
```

APPSCRIPT.JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $appfooter = $('#appfooter');
     show_footer();
});


function is_touch_device() {
   return !! ('ontouchstart' in window);
}

function show_footer() {
   var open = false;
   $appfooter.click(function() {
    console.log("show_footer");
        if (open == false) {
            $appfooter.addClass("transition");
            open = true;
        } else {
            $appfooter.removeClass("transition");
            open = false;
        }
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is simple ;). Assuming that you want to show the footer, `#appfooter .transition` applies to elements which have the `transition` style that are descendants of the `appfooter` element. Use `#appfooter.transition`, or simply `.transition` instead. (I'm sure you must have just missed this by mistake.)

As a bonus here is some simplified JS for you:

```
var appfooter = document.getElementById("appfooter");
appfooter.onclick = function () {
    appfooter.classList.toggle("transition");
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/MD8HL/

Comment: ah the space gotcha!  Thanks for the short cut.  I tried toggle but I needed the classList on there.  Much thanks

Comment: Sometimes it just takes a fresh pair of eyes. If you want to use jQuery you can indeed use `toggleClass` like this `$("#appfooter").toggleClass("transition");`. `classList` is a pure JS thing (which I have more experience in than jQuery which is why I used it). The choice is yours!